# Running applescript in new terminal tab and do file logging

Tags: file, logging, tabs, terminal, applescript

I need to do the following thing but I'm unable to find it in the forum. If any link exists kindly redirect me to it.

I need to invoke an applescript from a running terminal window . How do I make sure that the applescript is running in a new tab and not in a new window. Also, I'm supposed to watch some exceptions in this new tab but is it possible to simultaneously view in terminal and log the exception details in a separate file with some time stamp?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why would you want to run an AppleScript in a terminal window?! Why would you even think that you can? Wouldn't you rather concentrate on running an AppleScript after a link is clicked?

Comment: Basically I have frequent ssh operations on a remote machine. I'm interested in checking error/exception logs and process them in a file. Since the task is repetitive I think it's better to use a script that can help me in doing this task. Hope that clarifies your doubt. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to make an AppleScript that does the SSH operation for you or do you want it to analyse the log files only? You might want to include this info in your question.

Comment: The apple script will first do ssh to a remote machine then has to run certain unix commands the output of which needs to be stored in a log file. I've already include that in my question , the apples script is supposed to do both sshlogin and store the output of unix commands in a log file. The output of unix commands in my case displays exception details of some other already running process, if any.

Comment: Why not use a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run an AppleScript *in* the Terminal, but you can run an AppleScript *from* the Terminal. Using the `osascript` command, you can run an AppleScript from file or run a statement using AppleScript.

```
osascript "file path here" [arguments] # runs an AppleScript from a file with optional arguments

osascript -e 'AppleScript statement' # runs one line of AppleScript code from Terminal
```

Note: the -e flag can be used as many times as you like to make a fully functional AppleScript (line by line) from Terminal. Just add another flag after a line of code and continue coding.

If you want to log or print something from AppleScript in the Terminal window, you can use  `log "hello world"` in your AppleScript code.